# Python PIL ValueError: images do not match

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm playing around with PIL and came across this problem and I can't see where in the docs I'm going wrong. Here is my simple code

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageChops import difference

imageA = Image.open("image1.png")
imageB = Image.open("image2.png")

if imageA.size == imageB.size:
    diff = difference(imageA, imageB)
    diff.save("test.png")
```

which gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\[XXX]\box-test.py", line 8, in <module>
    diff = difference(imageA, imageB)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageChops.py", line 123, in difference
    return image1._new(image1.im.chop_difference(image2.im))
ValueError: images do not match
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `imageA.mode == imageB.mode`?

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with the image modes, they had to be the same!

Comment: Has `image1.png` the same dimensions as `image2.png` ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The documentation for this function doesn't tell much in fact. So let me try to clarify it a little. First, the sizes of the images are irrelevant to whether the function works or not, it internally checks for a size that both images fit.

Now, when can you actually compare the images by using the function `ImageChops.difference` ?

First, both images have to have pixels that can be stored in an unsigned byte. This is a very common type of image, but this excludes comparison between images even if they are the same mode. So, you cannot compare an image `x` and `y` when one or /both/ of them have a mode of: `F`, `I`, `I;16`, `I;16L`, `I;16B`, `BGR;15`, `BGR;16`, `BGR;24`, or `BGR;32`. Just to make it clear: it doesn't matter if both images are in the same mode if they happen to be in one of the modes above, the function will refuse to work.

So, the comparison can be done when the images are in the modes `1`, `P`, `L`, `LA`, `RGB`, `RGBA`, `RGBX`, `RGBa`, `CMYK`, or `YCbCr` as long as they have the same number of bands. This means the images don't have to have the same mode to be compared. For instance, `difference(x.convert('CMYK'), x.convert('RGBA'))` or `difference(x.convert('1'), x.convert('P'))` work just fine. Of course this means `difference(x.convert('LA'), x.convert('L'))`, fails. Finally, the resulting image will always have the mode equal to the first image passed to the function.

This is valid at least for the PIL 1.1.7.

Answer (score 2):

just verify the size of each image ( for example 1024 x 1024) for each layer and image