# discord.py bot using Pillow - ValueError: images do not match

Tags: python, discord, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord.py bot with a command that takes a tagged user's avatar, puts a transparent image on top, and then sends the edited photo back. I've been mashing together scraps of code from tutorials and other StackOverflow questions, so I'm not completely confident in what my code is doing. Currently it is not working because I keep getting an error in the command line. Below is the code for the bot command:

```
@scb.command(name='smack', description="smack cam someone", pass_context=True)
async def smack(ctx, member: Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    smackfile=r"E:\Smack Cam Bot\pie.png"
    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    providedimage = Image.open(data)
    pie = Image.open(smackfile)
    smack = Image.new("RGBA", providedimage.size)
    smack = Image.alpha_composite(smack, pie)
    smack.save("smack.png")
    await scb.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "smack.png")
```

Here is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command smack:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aj-ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "smackbot.py", line 37, in smack
    smack = Image.alpha_composite(smack, pie)
  File "C:\Users\aj-ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2979, in alpha_composite
    return im1._new(core.alpha_composite(im1.im, im2.im))
ValueError: images do not match
```

I haven't used Python very much, aside from a bit of Pygame. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Have you tried checking for the image modes [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291641/python-pil-valueerror-images-do-not-match)

Comment: @Ceres I don't know what this means. What would I have to do to make them the correct mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Twitter user __hetz, I can answer my own StackOverflow post.

The dimensions of both images had to match. That was it.
Also, I found an easier way to convert an avatar asset into a .PNG image in the size I needed:

`await ctx.author.avatar_url_as(format="png",size=128).save(fp="avatar.png")`

I was also using the wrong variable name in the alpha_composite line, so it should instead be:

`smack = Image.alpha_composite(providedimage, pie)`

And, last but not least, the function I was using to send messages was outdated. It should instead be:

`await ctx.message.channel.send(file=discord.File("smack.png"))`

Hopefully this can help some more dumb teenagers trying to make their own Discord bots.